# Which groups in a data.table share a corresponding set of dates

Tags: r, data.table

### Example

```
set.seed(2016)
dt <- data.table(
  Grp = sample(1000, 1000000, replace=TRUE),
  Date = as.Date("2016-1-1") + sample(365, 1000000, replace=TRUE)
)
dt <- unique(dt)

dt[order(Grp, Date)]
         Grp       Date
     1:    1 2016-01-02
     2:    1 2016-01-03
     3:    1 2016-01-05
     4:    1 2016-01-06
     5:    1 2016-01-07
    ---                
341526: 1000 2016-12-27
341527: 1000 2016-12-28
341528: 1000 2016-12-29
341529: 1000 2016-12-30
341530: 1000 2016-12-31
```

How do I know which (if any) groups share the exact same set of dates?  I guess I can `dcast` the data and then search for matching rows, but is there a better way?

Comment: Using dcast and then duplicated on the date columns should do it.

Comment: That's what I did and it worked.  I'm just wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this, in case the cardinality of Date were very high.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392332/find-all-duplicated-records-in-data-table-not-all-but-one The answers provided here might interest you then.

Comment: Your example contains zero instances of the feature you're asking about: `dcast(dt, Grp ~ Date, fun=function(x) length(x) > 0)[, uniqueN(.SD), .SDcols=!"Grp"]` Not sure what you have in mind to do with such a result anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As @Frank points out, your example doesn't actually include any examples.

I think probably your best bet is something like the following:

```
dt_agg = dt[order(Date), .(dates = list(Date), count = .N), by = Grp]
setkey(dt_agg, count)

dt_agg[ , if (.N > 1L && any(duplicated(setDT(transpose(dates))))) .SD, 
        by = count]
```

The key efficiency (I think) is not to bother running comparison unless two `Grp`s have the same number of unique `Date`s in the first place (hence grouping by `count`).

Within `count`, actually figuring out which `Grp`s contain set-identical `Date`s I'm a bit less confident on (also the code as is doesn't *exactly* pull out *which* `Grp`s are identical, but I don't think that's a far stretch from the code presented here.

Anyway this code ran on my machine almost instantly, so it's hard to evaluate efficiency.